# How to save auto generated multiple textInput Array value in mysql using Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Hello i want to save multiple form field value into MySQL database table using `Yii2` with out writing any custom query code. My table structure is where id primary key, auto_incremented. My array structure is given below

Form field is

```
   <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_degree[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Degree','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Degree')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_min[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Minute','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Minute')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_second[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Second','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Second')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_degree[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Degree','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Degree')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_min[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Minute','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Minute')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_second[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Second','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Second')->label(false)?></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_degree[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Degree','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Degree')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_min[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Minute','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Minute')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_second[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Second','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Second')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_degree[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Degree','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Degree')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_min[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Minute','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Minute')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_second[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Second','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Second')->label(false)?></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_degree[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Degree','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Degree')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_min[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Minute','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Minute')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'lat_second[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Second','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Second')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_degree[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Degree','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Degree')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_min[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Minute','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Minute')->label(false)?></td>
              <td><?= $form->field($coordinatemodel,'long_second[]')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Second','data-validation'=>'required number','data-validation-error-msg'=>'*Required','required'=>'required'])->label('Second')->label(false)?></td>
            </tr> 

id lat_degree lat_min lat_second long_degree long_min long_second
1  50         50      50          55          55       55
2  60         60      60          65          65       65
3  65         65      65          70          70       70
```

[image: My Array Structure is like below]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an explanation on this from the [docs on tabular input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html). You can alter your `actionCreate` to include this.

First, you will need to [create an array of models](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html#creating-a-dynamic-set-of-new-records) first to be populated:

```
$count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('CoordinateDetails', []));
$coordinateDetails = [new CoordinateDetail()];
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $coordinateDetails[] = new CoordinateDetail();
}
```

You can then use [loadMultiple](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#loadMultiple()-detail) and [validateMultiple](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#validateMultiple()-detail) to populate and validate your models. You will however have to loop through your models in order to save them:

```
if (CoordinateDetail::loadMultiple($coordinateDetails, Yii::$app->request->post()) 
    && CoordinateDetail::validateMultiple($coordinateDetails)) {
    foreach ($coordinateDetails as $coordinateDetail) {
        //do any other thing here e.g. setting foreign keys
        $coordinateDetail->save(false);
    }
    return $this->redirect('index');
}
else {
    // do something for the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use batchInsert Method:

```
        \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('yourtable', ['lat_degree','lat_min','lat_second',...],$CoordinatesDetail )
        ->bindValue(':id', 1)
        ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

When i have these kind of scenario in my project then i use [yii2-dynamicform](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform) extension which states:

> It is widget to yii2 framework to clone form elements in a nested manner, maintaining accessibility.

Check it's demo [here](http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo1/create).